# How to query a database without trigger a button -flutter

Tags: sql-server, flutter, dart

i have a `ElevatedButton` like this

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(
                  () {
                    cetak("SELECT CUST_NAME FROM ts_custxm ");
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                child: Text(
                  "Cetak",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            )
```

and this is my `Cetak()` Method

```
  cetak(String query) async {
    var req = await SqlConn.readData(query);
    var parsedJson = jsonDecode(req);
    debugPrint(res.toString());
    setState(() {
      res = parsedJson;
    });
  }
```

The problem is, when i want to query using `cetak()` i must trigger my `ElevatedButton`

is there any ways to query without using some button?

also im using `SQL_CONN` dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it in `initState()`, now when you do this, before your page loaded `cetak()` have been called :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    cetak("SELECT CUST_NAME FROM ts_custxm ");
    
  }
```